# Javascript onClick pass php string variable

Tags: javascript, php

I have this php code snippet and i want to pass string in onclick function. if i just add php variable it will print the string as 3rd argument but sending me error undefined "String Value".

```
 $mydata_rankings .= "[  \"$captainId\" ,\"$captain_name\", \"$phone\"
 ,\"$email\", \"$points\", \"$rank\", \"<a href='#'
 onclick='updaterank($captainId,$points,$rank)'>Approve</a>\"], ";
```

The 3rd argument $rank is string first 2 are numbers so no problem.

HTML output:

```
<a href="#" onclick="updaterank(112,120,Gold)"> Approve </a>
```

Comment: What is the expected output? `php` runs on the server-side, while `javascipt` runs only on the client-side..

Comment: @Ahmad the onclick function should run. its not running because its a string i think i have to send string with single quotes ?

Comment: Can you show the HTML result of this code?

Comment: <a href="#" onclick="updaterank(112,120,Gold)"> Approve </a>

Comment: `$mydata_rankings .= "[  \"` - what is that supposed to be - poor man’s JSON? Don’t assemble stuff like this manually - create the proper data structure, and then use `json_encode`!

Comment: @misorude this is not json its a php array with different values...

Comment: No, that is _not_ an array, it is a _string_ value. (And the content of that string appears to be JSON, which again, should not be assembled manually.)

Comment: @misorude any solution with current code ?

Comment: Why? This is absolutely trivial to rewrite using an array and json_encode - and it will be less error prone then, because json_encode will take care of encoding special characters according to JSON syntax, that you might otherwise miss.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `Gold` might not be defined.

You may have wanted it to be string, so enclose `$rank` between single quotes.

```
onclick='updaterank($captainId,$points,$rank)'
```

change it to:

```
onclick='updaterank($captainId,$points,\'$rank\')'
```

here is the complete code:

```
$mydata_rankings .= "[  \"$captainId\" ,\"$captain_name\", \"$phone\"
 ,\"$email\", \"$points\", \"$rank\", \"<a href='#'
 onclick='updaterank($captainId,$points,\'" . $rank . "\')'>Approve</a>\"], ";
```

Comment: I have tried '$rank' but it displays $rank as 3rd argument.

Comment: @DanishJamshed I have updated my answer to force `php` to substitute the value of `$rank`

Comment: Thanks Ahmed for your help but for some reasons this isn't working as well. i will share the html generated with your code.

Comment: <a href="#" onclick ="updaterank(1132,271.99,"gold')'="")Approve</a>  this is the html with your code

Comment: where does the `=` appear from? You need to fix the php code to prevent adding more that valid javascript function call. @DanishJamshed

Comment: not sure from where its coming = the variable contains Gold in it